# C - printf("%s") show Symbols

Tags: c, printf

I need your help because when I print the values ​​of atual->chave they return Symbols.
this is the code:

```
void mostrar(struct tLdde *l, int modo)
{
    struct tItem *atual;
    char *chave;

    if(modo == CABECA)
    {
        atual = l->inicio;
        while(atual != NULL)
        {
            chave = atual->chave;
            printf("%s ", &chave);
            atual = atual->proximo;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        atual = l->final;
        while(atual != NULL)
        {
            chave = atual->chave;
            printf("%s ", &chave);
            atual = atual->anterior;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

and this is the output:

**Spea { Obam{ iPhoP{ Pott8{**

Answer (score 3):

use

```
printf("%s ", chave);
```

and not

```
printf("%s ", &chave);
```

remove the &

Comment: I try this, but the program stops when arrives in this line

Comment: That implies that you haven't assigned `atual->chave` correctly.  The root of the problem is in the code that sets up your list.